# Does sagepay have any library or SDK for in app payment for iOS and/or Android?

Tags: android, ios, opayo

I have searched many things on Sagepay but could not find a link to go to developer forum for Sagepay and I tried to find library or SDK for iOS and/or Android, but unable to get succeed.

Kindly let me know, if Sagepay provides library for iOS and/or for Android.If yes, is it possible to provide me link for downloading integration documents?

Thanks

Comment: m also searching for it if you do find it let me know please on abdul.cabcall @ gmail . com

Comment: @iMOBDEV had you implement the sagepay payment gateway in android, had you get any solution

Answer (score 1):

Check this url https://github.com/ColorsSoftwarePvtLtd/SagePay-Android

SagePay-Android

For more details visit Sage pay form integration https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/integrations String encryption using below code

```
                  FormApiEncryptionHelper helper=new FormApiEncryptionHelper(); 
                  String encryptedString=helper.encrypt("UTF-8","TPjs72eMz5qBnaTa", registration) ;
```

For more details visit http://www.colorssoftware.com/blog/how-to-integrate-sagepay-payment-gateway-into-android-native-app/

Comment: In this link form registration url is for sandbox( test account ), for live environment what should be the form registration url.

Comment: is there any new link as its is very old github link.

Answer (score 0):

Sage Pay validation is per IP address, so unless you are sure the device connects always from the same IP address then it wont work, unless you use FORM integration.